# Roogle Vision Package

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have a dataset (photos) with two column (one for the images ID and one with the images url).
After I plugged-in my Google Cloud Platform credentials, I ran the following code to generate keywords:

```
require(RoogleVision) 
#add extra columns for 10 x 3 rows of data (keyword, probability score, and topicality score)
photos[,3:32] <- NA
##Loop##
for(i in 1:length(photos$url)){ 
  te <- getGoogleVisionResponse(photos$url[i], feature="LABEL_DETECTION", numResults = 10)
  
  #If not successful, return NA matrix
  if(length(te)==1){ te <- matrix(NA, 10,4)} 
  if (is.null(te)){ te <- matrix(NA, 10,4)}
  
  te <- te[,2:4]
  
  #if successful but no. of keywords <10, put NAs in remaining rows
  if(length(te[,1])<10){
    te[(length(te[,1])+1):10,] <- NA}  
  
  #Append all data!
  photos[i, 3:12] <- te[,1] #keywords
  photos[i, 13:22] <- te[,2] #probability scores
  photos[i, 23:32] <- te[,3] #topicality scores
  
  cat("<row", i, "/", length(photos[,1]), "> ")
  }
```

I got the following error

```
Error: Assigned data `te[, 1]` must be compatible with row subscript `i`.
x 1 row must be assigned.
x Assigned data has 10 rows.
ℹ Row updates require a list value. Do you need `list()` or `as.list()`?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: What does this question have to do with Flickr?

Comment: The error code has nothing to do with Flickr. The images were retrieved from Flickr and I am trying to analyze the content using Roogle Vision.